# Get intersection point of rectangle and line

Tags: c#, wpf, math

I need get intersection point of rectangle and line. 
I have point B inside rectangle(center of rectangle) and have point A outside. And i need to find point C on one of rectangle borders.
Also I get width and height of rectangle.

[image]

All this will be **WPF** application, so if any build in functions i will be very happy.

Comment: a rectangle is just 4 lines. Apply line/line intersection testing 4 times.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the intersection point between a line and a rectangle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585525/how-to-find-the-intersection-point-between-a-line-and-a-rectangle)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution for C#, WPF:

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Get Intersection point
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="a1">a1 is line1 start</param>
    /// <param name="a2">a2 is line1 end</param>
    /// <param name="b1">b1 is line2 start</param>
    /// <param name="b2">b2 is line2 end</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Vector? Intersects(Vector a1, Vector a2, Vector b1, Vector b2)
    {
        Vector b = a2 - a1;
        Vector d = b2 - b1;
        var bDotDPerp = b.X * d.Y - b.Y * d.X;

        // if b dot d == 0, it means the lines are parallel so have infinite intersection points
        if (bDotDPerp == 0)
            return null;

        Vector c = b1 - a1;
        var t = (c.X * d.Y - c.Y * d.X) / bDotDPerp;
        if (t < 0 || t > 1)
            {
            return null;
        }

        var u = (c.X * b.Y - c.Y * b.X) / bDotDPerp;
        if (u < 0 || u > 1)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return a1 + t * b;
    }
```

**Edit**
 Found [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746274/line-intersection-with-aabb-rectangle/3746601#3746601) to SO question where the answer above comes from.

Answer (score 4):

This is basic math solving line-line intersection, check out topcoder for a [tutorial](http://www.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=geometry2):

> Line-Line Intersection One of the most
>   common tasks you will find in geometry
>   problems is line intersection. Despite
>   the fact that it is so common, a lot
>   of coders still have trouble with it.
>   The first question is, what form are
>   we given our lines in, and what form
>   would we like them in? Ideally, each
>   of our lines will be in the form
>   Ax+By=C, where A, B and C are the
>   numbers which define the line.
>   However, we are rarely given lines in
>   this format, but we can easily
>   generate such an equation from two
>   points. Say we are given two different
>   points, (x1, y1) and (x2, y2), and
>   want to find A, B and C for the
>   equation above. We can do so by
>   setting A = y2-y1 B = x1-x2 C =
>   A*x1+B*y1

Comment: That should be much quicker than my method. +1

Comment: That formula makes no sense at all. A, B, and C should all be Points and that yields single values.

Comment: @msarchet: That's only a portion of the algorithm, and A, B and C have different meaning in the tutorial than in the question.

Comment: @belisarius: See @David Heffernan's comment to OP's question - just try all 4 sides of the rectangle to find the intersection point - after all a rectangle is just 4 *lines*.

Comment: @Broken My comment pointed to two issues: You should take care of overflows when lines are parallel, and also, after applying the line intersection algorithm ... what? Should you always do it four times or is there a way to know which line/s are the possible intersections? But don't mind, I was just trying to help you to post a complete answer, as yours is the top voted so far :)

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing WPF, or any of its functions, this is how I would do it:

1. Create a temporary point D that creates a right angle between B and C.
2. The length of CD should be known since B is at the center of the rectangle. Therefore, it should be simple to compute the length of BD.
3. Determine the length of BC by sqrt( (BD)^2 + (CD)^2 ).
4. Given the position of A, you know if C is before or after the midpoint of the rectangle's side. Therefore, you can use the length of BC to calculate the position of C on the side.

Answer (score 2):

With ax and ay the coordinates of A, and bx, by the coordinates of B, and assuming the centre of the rectangle with width w and height h is at {0,0} the following should work

```
IntersectionRectangleLine[{ax_, ay_}, {bx_, by_}, h_, w_] :=
  Module[{\[Mu]r, \[Mu]l, \[Mu]t, \[Mu]b},
    {\[Mu]r, \[Mu]l, \[Mu]t, \[Mu]b} = {-((-2 ay bx + 2 ax by - ax w + 
      bx w)/((ay - by) h)), -((-2 ay bx + 2 ax by + ax w - 
      bx w)/((ay - by) h)), -((
     2 ay bx - 2 ax by - ay h + by h)/((ax - bx) w)), -((
     2 ay bx - 2 ax by + ay h - by h)/((ax - bx) w))};
 Which[
   -1 <= \[Mu]r <= 1, {0, w/2} + \[Mu]r {h/2, 0},
   -1 <= \[Mu]l <= 1, {0, -w/2} + \[Mu]l {h/2, 0},
   -1 <= \[Mu]t <= 1, {h/2, 0} + \[Mu]t {0, w/2},
   -1 <= \[Mu]b <= 1, {-h/2, 0} + \[Mu]b {0, w/2}
 ]
]
```

This based on the solutions for the intersection of the four lines making up the triangle

```
  In[114]:= Solve[Thread[\[Lambda] ({bx, by} - {ax, ay}) + {ax, ay} == {0, w/2} + \[Mu] {h/2, 0}], \[Mu], {\[Lambda]}]

 Out[114]= {{\[Mu] -> -((-2 ay bx + 2 ax by - ax w + bx w)/((ay - by) h))}}
```

(top line as an example here).

And for Evgeny, this is how it looks on my screen. Quite a lot more readable.

[image: prettier version of code]

Comment: It was tagged Mathematica when I read the question. This has been removed since. I guess by Belisarius. I agree this is not a Mathematica problem.

Comment: What a mess. What language is this?

Comment: For me Mathematica is the computer algebra package developed by Wolram Research, Inc. The gibberish you see is because you see the ASCII representation of some Greek symbols I used.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the dimensions of the rectangle, which I assume you do"

- `rX` rectangle width
- `rY` rectangle height
- `Ay` A's Y Position
- `Ax` A's X Position
- `By` B's Y Position
- `Bx` B's X Position
- `Cy` C's Y Position
- `Cx` C's X Position

`Cy = By + rY / 2`

The C Position is at the top of the rectangle, so it is the By position + half of the rY position

Then we just need to calculate the `Cx`position.

`Cx = (Bx + ((Ax - Bx) / (Ay - By)) * Cy)`

You can get the X and Y Coordiantes for A and B by using the `Point`

Answer (score 1):

[image: Line Intersection Possibilities in Rectangle]

Hope It works 100%

I am also had this same problem. So after two days of hard effort finally I created this method,

Main method,

```
    // Tuple<entryPoint, exitPoint, lineStatus>
    private Tuple<Point, Point, Line> GetIntersectionPoint(Point a, Point b, Rectangle rect)
    {
        if (IsWithinRectangle(a, rect) && IsWithinRectangle(b, rect))
        {
            // Can't set null to Point that's why I am returning just empty object
            return new Tuple<Point, Point, Line>(new Point(), new Point(), Line.InsideTheRectangle);
        }
        else if (!IsWithinRectangle(a, rect) && !IsWithinRectangle(b, rect))
        {
            if (!LineIntersectsRectangle(a, b, rect))
            {
                // Can't set null to Point that's why I am returning just empty object
                return new Tuple<Point, Point, Line>(new Point(), new Point(), Line.NoIntersection);
            }

            Point entryPoint = new Point();
            Point exitPoint = new Point();

            bool entryPointFound = false;

            // Top Line of Chart Area
            if (LineIntersectsLine(a, b, new Point(0, 0), new Point(rect.Width, 0)))
            {
                entryPoint = GetPointFromYValue(a, b, 0);
                entryPointFound = true;
            }
            // Right Line of Chart Area
            if (LineIntersectsLine(a, b, new Point(rect.Width, 0), new Point(rect.Width, rect.Height)))
            {
                if (entryPointFound)
                    exitPoint = GetPointFromXValue(a, b, rect.Width);
                else
                {
                    entryPoint = GetPointFromXValue(a, b, rect.Width);
                    entryPointFound = true;
                }
            }
            // Bottom Line of Chart
            if (LineIntersectsLine(a, b, new Point(0, rect.Height), new Point(rect.Width, rect.Height)))
            {
                if (entryPointFound)
                    exitPoint = GetPointFromYValue(a, b, rect.Height);
                else
                {
                    entryPoint = GetPointFromYValue(a, b, rect.Height);
                }
            }
            // Left Line of Chart
            if (LineIntersectsLine(a, b, new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, rect.Height)))
            {
                exitPoint = GetPointFromXValue(a, b, 0);
            }

            return new Tuple<Point, Point, Line>(entryPoint, exitPoint, Line.EntryExit);
        }
        else
        {
            Point entryPoint = GetEntryIntersectionPoint(rect, a, b);
            return new Tuple<Point, Point, Line>(entryPoint, new Point(), Line.Entry);
        }
    }
```

Supporting methods,

```
    enum Line
    {
        // Inside the Rectangle so No Intersection Point(Both Entry Point and Exit Point will be Null)
        InsideTheRectangle,

        // One Point Inside the Rectangle another Point Outside the Rectangle. So it has only Entry Point
        Entry,

        // Both Point Outside the Rectangle but Intersecting. So It has both Entry and Exit Point
        EntryExit,

        // Both Point Outside the Rectangle and not Intersecting. So doesn't has both Entry and Exit Point
        NoIntersection
    }

    private Point GetEntryIntersectionPoint(Rectangle rect, Point a, Point b)
    {
        // For top line of the rectangle
        if (LineIntersectsLine(new Point(0, 0), new Point(rect.Width, 0), a, b))
        {
            return GetPointFromYValue(a, b, 0);
        }
        // For right side line of the rectangle
        else if (LineIntersectsLine(new Point(rect.Width, 0), new Point(rect.Width, rect.Height), a, b))
        {
            return GetPointFromXValue(a, b, rect.Width);
        }
        // For bottom line of the rectangle
        else if (LineIntersectsLine(new Point(0, rect.Height), new Point(rect.Width, rect.Height), a, b))
        {
            return GetPointFromYValue(a, b, rect.Height);
        }
        // For left side line of the rectangle
        else
        {
            return GetPointFromXValue(a, b, 0);
        }
    }

    public bool LineIntersectsRectangle(Point p1, Point p2, Rectangle r)
    {
        return LineIntersectsLine(p1, p2, new Point(r.X, r.Y), new Point(r.X + r.Width, r.Y)) ||
               LineIntersectsLine(p1, p2, new Point(r.X + r.Width, r.Y), new Point(r.X + r.Width, r.Y + r.Height)) ||
               LineIntersectsLine(p1, p2, new Point(r.X + r.Width, r.Y + r.Height), new Point(r.X, r.Y + r.Height)) ||
               LineIntersectsLine(p1, p2, new Point(r.X, r.Y + r.Height), new Point(r.X, r.Y)) ||
               (r.Contains(p1) && r.Contains(p2));
    }

    private bool LineIntersectsLine(Point l1p1, Point l1p2, Point l2p1, Point l2p2)
    {
        float q = (l1p1.Y - l2p1.Y) * (l2p2.X - l2p1.X) - (l1p1.X - l2p1.X) * (l2p2.Y - l2p1.Y);
        float d = (l1p2.X - l1p1.X) * (l2p2.Y - l2p1.Y) - (l1p2.Y - l1p1.Y) * (l2p2.X - l2p1.X);

        if (d == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }

        float r = q / d;

        q = (l1p1.Y - l2p1.Y) * (l1p2.X - l1p1.X) - (l1p1.X - l2p1.X) * (l1p2.Y - l1p1.Y);
        float s = q / d;

        if (r < 0 || r > 1 || s < 0 || s > 1)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    // For Large values, processing with integer is not working properly
    // So I here I am dealing only with double for high accuracy
    private Point GetPointFromYValue(Point a, Point b, double y)
    {
        double x1 = a.X, x2 = b.X, y1 = a.Y, y2 = b.Y;
        double x = (((y - y1) * (x2 - x1)) / (y2 - y1)) + x1;
        return new Point((int)x, (int)y);
    }

    // For Large values, processing with integer is not working properly
    // So here I am dealing only with double for high accuracy
    private Point GetPointFromXValue(Point a, Point b, double x)
    {
        double x1 = a.X, x2 = b.X, y1 = a.Y, y2 = b.Y;
        double y = (((x - x1) * (y2 - y1)) / (x2 - x1)) + y1;
        return new Point((int)x, (int)y);
    }

    // rect.Contains(point) is not working properly in some cases.
    // So here I created my own method
    private bool IsWithinRectangle(Point a, Rectangle rect)
    {
        return a.X >= rect.X && a.X <= rect.X + rect.Width && a.Y >= rect.Y && a.Y <= rect.Y + rect.Height;
    }
```