# Intersection point of a vector or its extension with surrounding rectangle

Tags: math, vector, geometry, trigonometry, computational-geometry

I would like to find the intersection point of a vector or its extension with the surrounding rectangle, that is, in the image (1) and (2), given `(x1, y1), (x2, y2), (a1, a2), (b1, b2)`, we would like to obtain the point `(c1, c2)`.

[image]

I have found the article [Find collision point between vector and fencing rectangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/625266/find-collision-point-between-vector-and-fencing-rectangle) but, since the positive y-axis is downward in python/windows, I could not manage the equations and parameters to acheive the correct result. The two following links are also related.

[intersection between a line and square](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58055629/intersection-between-a-line-and-square)

[Get intersection point of rectangle and line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221725/get-intersection-point-of-rectangle-and-line).

But they do not include the extension of the vector/line segment.
How should the equations change to obtain the correct result?

Comment: My cited [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58055629/intersection-between-a-line-and-square) is perfectly fine for your problem. `ox,oy` in my answer might be both inside and outside.

Comment: Why would the direction of the y axis affect the equations or the parameters? Coordinates are coordinates.

Comment: @Sneftel y-axis affects since, the same line will have a slop with opposite sign in the coordinate system on the paper vs. opencv/python. In python, (0,0) is top left corner and y increases downward, while, in conventional coordinate system in mathematics, y increases upward.

Comment: Right. Which affects both the inputs and the outputs, resulting in the algorithm working in either case. The number 3 doesn't care whether it's left or right.

Comment: @MBo I can not clearly get from your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58055629/intersection-between-a-line-and-square) what if the vector is fully inside the rectangle? i.e. Does it give the solution for the extension of the vector intersecting the rectangle like figure (1) in my question?

Comment: Yes. The second point just gives a direction.

Comment: "since the positive y-axis is downward": in your case or in the case of the article ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust my case. This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58055629/intersection-between-a-line-and-square) is the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A point on the ray is given by the coordinates `(a1 + t (b1 - a1), a2 + t (b2 - a2))`.

The intersections are obtained by solving the four equations

```
a1 + t (b1 - a1) = x1
a1 + t (b1 - a1) = x2
a2 + t (b2 - a2) = y1
a2 + t (b2 - a2) = y2
```

for `t` and taking the *smallest positive solution*. If some of the coefficients of `t` is zero, just ignore the corresponding equation.

The orientations of the axis play no role.