# Algorith problem Decode Hex to set output

Tags: javascript, algorithm, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I got an algorithm that I need to solve. Unfortunately, I can't even find a clue about a solution. Please help me to understand how to solve this problem.

**The problem**

An imaginary pen input device sends hex data to the device to display a line with color.

**Examples  Draw simple Green Line**

Set color to green, draw a line from (0,0) to (4000, 4000). Filled circle in this diagram indicates a pen down
position, empty circle indicates pen up position.

> Input Data: F0A04000417F4000417FC040004000804001C05F205F20804000
>
> Output:
>  CLR; CO 0 255 0 255; 
>  MV (0, 0); 
>  PEN DOWN;
>   
>  MV (4000, 4000);
>  PEN UP;

I got the information about each output. 
[image: output data]

This code is for encoding hex to binary. I guess that the solution would encode the hex to binary, and manipulate it to set correct output.

```
function hex2bin(hex){
    return (parseInt(hex, 16).toString(2))}
```

The expected result has the same output as Examaple's with the input data.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between internal computer data format and textual representation for human reading?

Comment: In my understanding, Internal computer data represented as like "010101" or "A0F0" which uses just 0 and 1 or hex. Please let me know if I'm right or wrong. and how to use this knowledge to solve this.

Comment: There are bytes. We can see the same byte as integer 65, hex 0x41, binary 0100 0001, ASCII char "A". So it is worth to specify what your input data means.  `sends hex data` ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, some important information is missing from your question: how the numbers like 4000 (in the result) are encoded in the hex format.

I think I could derive it from the example though

### The peculiar numeric encoding

Numbers seem to be encoded with 2 bytes (4 hex characters) each, where the most significant bits of these 2 bytes (bits 7 and 15) do not contribute to the value (they are always zero).

Furthermore, the remaining 14 bits are encoded in [offset binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offset_binary), where the most significant of those 14 bits is the inverted sign bit.

This means that "4000" is zero, "0000" is -8192 (the minimum), and "7F7F" is 8191 (the maximum). Note that the one but last character cannot be more than 7, since that would set a bit that is not used in this (custom) encoding.

This was the hardest part to derive from the little info you provided.

### On the Example

The input example you provided can be broken down into pieces like this:

```
opcode | argument(s)
-------+----------------------------
 "F0"  |
 "A0"  | "4000" "417F" "4000" "417F"
 "C0"  | "4000" "4000" 
 "80"  | "4001" 
 "C0"  | "5F20" "5F20"
 "80"  | "4000"
```

Using the numeric conversion discussed above, this would translate to:

```
opcode | argument(s)
-------+------------
  240  |
  160  | 0 255 0 255
  192  | 0 0
  128  | 1
  192  | 4000 4000
  128  | 0
```

And then it is a matter of following the instructions to turn that into the required output.

So the algorithm could first decode the input string into commands, where each command consists of an opcode and zero or more numeric arguments.

And then those commands could be turned into the required output by keeping track of whether the pen is down and what the current coordinates are:

```js
function decode(hex) {
    let commands = [];
    let command;
    for (let i = 0, len; i < hex.length; i+=len) {
        // Opcodes take 1 byte (i.e. 2 hex characters), and 
        // numbers take 2 bytes (4 characters)
        len = hex[i] >= "8" ? 2 : 4;
        let num = parseInt(hex.slice(i, i+len), 16);
        if (len === 2) { // opcode
            command = []; // start a new command
            commands.push(command);
        } else { // number
            // The encoded format is a custom one. This seems to be it:
            num = ((num & 0x7F00) >> 1) + (num & 0x7F) - 0x2000; 
        }
        command.push(num); // push opcode or argument in current command
    }
    return commands;
}

function disassemble(hex) {
    let isPenDown = false;
    let x = 0, y = 0;
    let output = "";
    let commands = decode(hex);
    for (let [opcode, ...args] of commands) {
        if (opcode === 0xF0) {
            x = y = 0;
            isPenDown = false;
            output += "CLR;\n";
        } else if (opcode === 0x80) {
            isPenDown = args[0] > 0;
            output += "PEN " + (isPenDown ? "DOWN" : "UP") + ";\n";
        } else if (opcode === 0xA0) {
            output += "CO " + args.join(" ") + ";\n";
        } else if (opcode === 0xC0) {
            let allPos = "", lastPos;
            for (let i = 0; i < args.length; i+=2) {
                x += args[i];
                y += args[i+1];
                lastPos = ` (${x}, ${y})`;
                if (isPenDown) allPos += lastPos;
            }
            output += "MV" + (allPos || lastPos) + ";\n";
        } // else: ignore unknown commands
    }
    return output;
}

// Sample:
console.log(disassemble("F0A04000417F4000417FC040004000804001C05F205F20804000"));
```

### More to do

In the screenshot of the problem, near the end, there is also mention of clipping movements to a bounding box. This goes beyond your question about decoding the hex input, so I will leave it at this. For the interested, you could check out Q&A about calculating line segment intersections, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746274/line-intersection-with-aabb-rectangle).

Comment: thank you for a great comment. It helps me a lot. You are right. I didn't describe how to decode the value. Your assumption is correct. The number is limited to be 14 bits (2 bytes).  Please allow me to ask more question. I should parse value by opcode. For instance, sort the input by the opcode and push the value after the opcode until new opcode appear. My question here is how to sort and parse the data because the information consists same hex range, so I don't know how to figure out which is opcode or value for the opcode.

Comment: Bytes are 2 hex characters. When first character is 8 or more it is an opcode. You can see that condition in the code I provided... where `len` is defined.

Comment: is sorry for causing you trouble to assign other question as duplicate. I misunderstood your answer and now recognized your answer is a perfect solution for the problem.