# How to store value to object effectively

Tags: javascript, algorithm, object

I'm tackling the problem for a week. However, I couldn't find a solution. I feel I'm in a maze now.

The problem is that how to pen's coordinates in a vector-based drawing system by decoding hex input.

Thank you so much in advance.

**Problem**

> Input Data:
>   F0A040004000417F417FC04000400090400047684F5057384000804001C0
>   5F204000400001400140400040007E405B2C4000804000
>   [image]

Pen move condinates
[image]

**This is my code**

```js
//Decode Value
penDecode = (hex) => {
    let decodeResult
    let hR = hex.slice(0, 2)
    let lR = hex.slice(2)

    let hByte = parseInt(hR, 16).toString(2).padStart(7, 0)
    let lByte = parseInt(lR, 16).toString(2).padStart(7, 0)
    let binary = hByte + lByte;
    decodeResult = (parseInt(hByte + lByte, 2)) - 8192

    return decodeResult
}



//Slice input
for (let i = 0, len; i < hex.length; i += len) {

    len = hex[i] >= '8' ? 2 : 4;
    let num = hex.slice(i, i + len)
    command.push(num)

    if (num.length === 2) {
        switch (num) {
            case 'C0':
                opcode = num;
                break;

            default:
                opcode = ''
        };
        else if (num.length === 4) {
            //decode HEX to the value 
            num = penDecode(num)
            switch (opcode) {
                case 'C0':
                    if (mvCurrentArr.length <= 1) {
                        mvCurrentArr.push(num)
                    } else {
                        mvArray.push(mvCurrentArr)
                        mv += `(${mvCurrentArr[1]},${mvCurrentArr[0]})`
                        mvCurrentArr = []
                        mvCurrentArr.push(num)
                        output += mv
                    }

            }
```

**Expected output**
Output become same as the picture above
MV (4000, 0) (4000, -8000) (-4000, -8000) (-4000, 0) (-500, 0);

Comment: what does it have to do with javascript though ?

Comment: @Noob well it's written in javascript...

Comment: @CalebGoodman sure, but  should it be in this category ?

Comment: @Noob typically you pick the category that your question is written in.  So yes javascript code should be in the javascript category.

Comment: @CalebGoodman oh i see, thanks. I didn't know i could post questions like this here.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm very new to be a developer, so if I use here in the wrong way. please correct me.

Comment: Can you elaborate what problem you're having is unclear what you're asking. I tried to understand your code, but there's not enough information. Your penDecode function does the same as `parseInt(hex, 16)-8192`

Comment: Your post is a little confusing. From what I understand, you are trying to decode a hex string into a JS object?

Comment: Why do you ask this again? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57720118/algorith-problem-decode-hex-to-set-output/57733803#57733803

Comment: You did not deal with any other opcode than `C0` here. Why? You already got an answer in the other question that dealt with the other opcodes as well, so why did you not use that answer? It provides the expected result when you pass it the input string you specified here...